# How to properly connect to Google Spreadsheets API?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, google-authentication, gspread

I want to connect to the Google Spreadsheets API with Python.

So I do:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 
'https://wwww.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('cred.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open('datatest').Sheet1

print(wks.get_all_records)
```

But I get this error

```
HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets is not a valid audience string.
```

How can I use Google-auth instead of gspread with this data?

Comment: Have you tried `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds` as in [gspread documentation](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html)

Comment: Ditch `oauth2client` as it is deprecated. `google-auth` works well with service accounts. There's also actual Google client libraries for python - you don't need `gspread` unless you want to use it instead. And if so, why wouldn't you tag this question with it?

Comment: @tehowch, I did not know it. Is there a place to see some running example with google-auth?  J.J.Hakala, yes, I have tried it but with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you input 4w !!!!

X 'https://wwww.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

O 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('CredentialsFile.json', scope)
ss_app = gspread.authorize(credentials=credentials)  # make sure your Google Sheets API is enabled
sht = ss_app.open('sheet_name_xxxx')  # In your spreadsheet, click the Share button and paste the client email as same as CredentialsFile.json.client_email, and make sure your Google Drive API is enabled
wks = sht.worksheet('worksheet_name_xxxx')
print(wks.acell('A1').value)
```

hope that it helps.